# Query to find subscriber in all data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a query or built in way in SFMC to view all data extension memberships for a single subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

No, there sure isn't.

But when you delete a subscriber using the [**Contact Delete**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) functionality in your parent business unit, it will remove subscribers from all sendable Data Extensions.